# Show does not combine the plots

Tags: plotting, complex

i've the following problem:

because it's not possible to plot complex numbers (or is it?) i created my own "function":

```
    complexPlot[cn_] := 
      Plot[0, {x, -100, 100}, 
           PlotRange -> {-500, 500},
           AspectRatio -> 1,  
           AxesLabel -> {Re, I },
           Epilog -> {Background -> None, PointSize[0.03], 
           Point[{{Re[cn[[1]]], Im[cn[[1]]]}, {Re[cn[[2]]], 
                 Im[cn[[2]]]}, {Re[cn[[3]]], Im[cn[[3]]]}}]}
  ]
```

with complexPlot, I can plot my complex Numbers, but i want to have one graphic for all my number pairs.

```
    myPlots = Table[
                    complexPlot[linPolesAll[[n]]],
                    {n, 1, 16}]

    Show[myPlots]
```

Does not work, it overlays all Plots with the last one (tried it with Show[myPlots[[1]],myPlots[[10]]])

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `Show` is *supposed* to overlay all the plots. (If this is not what you want, look at `Grid`, `GraphicsGrid`, `TableForm`, etc.) Is there some problem with *how* the overlay is occurring?

Comment: Only the first `Epilog` option setting is used by `Show`. The rest are ignored.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use

```
complexPlot[pts_]:=ListPlot[{Re@#,Im@#}&/@pts]
```

as your customly defined plot function?
The advantage is that this version shows the appropriate region,
not the hardcoded one you have in your version.

Answer (score 2):

In @Nasser's answer, one could directly use the built-in function `RandomComplex`:

```
poles = RandomComplex[{-100 - 100 I, 100 + 100 I}, {12, 3}];
```

And then, since you want to plot complex numbers and, except for graphics, Mathematica "prefers" complex number to reals, it seems silly to have to program complex things in terms of real and imaginary parts. This is where David Park's *Presentations* add-on ( http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html) can do the work for you:

```
Draw2D[{PointSize[Large], Red, ComplexPoint /@ poles},
       Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {Re, Im}, BaseStyle -> 12, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]