# How to plot complex values given by Solve

Tags: plotting, replacement, complex

## Update

```
Solve[N[Table[BernoulliB[n, z], {n, 10, 10}] == 0]]
```

> ```
> {{z -> -0.5841145496910024` - 0.435309007896589` I}, <<4>>}
> ```

I am then finding and replacing `z ->` with blank to get :

> ```
> {{-0.5841145496910024` - 0.435309007896589` I}, <<4>>}
> ```

I am then finding and replacing `` ` I} `` with `}` to get :

> ```
> {{-0.5841145496910024`-0.435309007896589}, <<4>>}
> ```

I am then finding and replacing `'` with `,` to get :

> ```
> {{-0.5841145496910024, -0.435309007896589}, <<4>>}
> ```

**My question is**, is there a way of doing this without all of the find & replace business?

---

## Old

I am generating a list from :

```
Solve[N[Table[BernoulliB[n, z], {n, 100, 100}] == 0]]
```

And then manually finding and replacing elements in the generated list such as `z ->` with `Blank`, then finding and replacing `, I}` with `}`, and so on. I am then producing a list plot form the resultant array. Is there a way of automating this process and producing a list plot directly?

Comment: What do you mean by " replacing , `I}` with `}`,"?

Comment: `({Re@z, Im@z} /. sol) // ListPlot` ?

Comment: Am I missing something: what's the purpose of using `Table` here? Why not just `Solve[N@BernoulliB[10, z] == 0, z]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First part of your question is answered in [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/5478).

How to plot complex points is described for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17544/5478).

What you need is what was my guess:

```
sol = Solve[N[Table[BernoulliB[n, z], {n, 10, 10}] == 0]];

{Re@z, Im@z} /. sol // ListPlot
```

[image]

Comment: @ Kuba Many thanks! This has saved me a great deal of time!

Comment: And congratulations on 10k. Really fast!

Comment: @cormullion Thank you, I enjoy being here :) Fast?, take a look at [ybeltukov's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov) rate :P

Answer (score 1):

If you use David Park's *Presentations* add-on (http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html), then there's no need for the artificial pulling apart of the complex roots into their real and imaginary parts; you can just treat complex numbers as complex numbers:

```
<< Presentations`

pts = z /. Solve[N@BernoulliB[10, z] == 0, z]
Draw2D[{PointSize[Medium], ComplexPoint /@ pts}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Murray Many thanks for your comment - will look into it.